# How to include a .phar and reference it

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, phar

My directory looks like this

[image]

Then my code looks like this:

```
require "aws.*";

use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
```

Is this the right way to do it?

It doesn't show me an error or anything so I don't know if it's working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
include 'aws.phar';
```

or

```
include 'phar://aws.phar/internal/file.php';
```

or read documentation about [using phar](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.php)

P.S. you cannot use wildcards in require or include.

P.P.S. `use` is not a reference. [Read more about use](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).